# Not able to run jbehave+selenium+groovy code

Tags: maven, selenium, jbehave

I am getting following error when running jbehave+selenium+groovy and the error is as follows:

```
 Plugin org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.10-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:jar:3.10-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Please find pom.xm here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.jbehave.tutorials</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <artifactId>etsy-stories-groovy-pico</artifactId>
  <name>Etsy.com Stories with Groovy and Pico</name>
  <description>JBehave stories verifying functionality of Etsy.com using Groovy and Pico</description>

  <properties>
    <jbehave.core.version>3.10-SNAPSHOT</jbehave.core.version>
    <jbehave.web.version>3.6-SNAPSHOT</jbehave.web.version>
    <jbehave.site.version>3.1.1</jbehave.site.version>
    <fluent.selenium.version>1.14.5</fluent.selenium.version>
    <selenium.version>2.40.0</selenium.version>
    <gmaven.version>1.3</gmaven.version>
    <groovy.version>1.8.6</groovy.version>
    <ignore.failures>true</ignore.failures>
    <meta.filter></meta.filter>
    <threads>1</threads>
    <storyTimeoutInSecs>250</storyTimeoutInSecs>
    <skip>false</skip>
    <stories>**/EtsyDotComStories.java</stories>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.core.version}</version>
      <classifier>resources</classifier>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave.site</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-site-resources</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.site.version}</version>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-web-selenium</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.web.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
          <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent</groupId>
      <artifactId>fluent-selenium</artifactId>
      <version>${fluent.selenium.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.tanob</groupId>
      <artifactId>groobe</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
      <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-pico</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
          <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.geb</groupId>
      <artifactId>geb-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
          <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${gmaven.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
              <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.7</artifactId>
              <version>${gmaven.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
              <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
              <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
          only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>copy</goal>
                      <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[${jbehave.core.version},)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[${gmaven.version},)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                      <goal>compile</goal>
                      <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                      <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/groovy</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/stories</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test 
            phase -->
          <skip>false</skip>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-resources-core</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jbehave/view</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
              <excludes>**/*.class</excludes>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jbehave-navigator</artifactId>
                  <version>${jbehave.core.version}</version>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jbehave.core.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>embeddable-stories</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>${stories}</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes />
              <ignoreFailureInStories>${ignore.failures}</ignoreFailureInStories>
              <ignoreFailureInView>${ignore.failures}</ignoreFailureInView>
              <threads>${threads}</threads>
              <skip>${skip}</skip>
              <storyTimeoutInSecs>${storyTimeoutInSecs}</storyTimeoutInSecs>
              <metaFilters>
                <metaFilter>${meta.filter}</metaFilter>
              </metaFilters>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>map-stories</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*StoryMaps.java</include>
              </includes>
              <metaFilters>
                <metaFilter>+category *</metaFilter>
                <metaFilter>+color *</metaFilter>
              </metaFilters>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>map-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report-stepdocs</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>${stories}</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>report-stepdocs-as-embeddables</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generateStubs</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>stable</id>
      <properties>
        <jbehave.core.version>3.9.1</jbehave.core.version>
        <jbehave.web.version>3.6-beta-2</jbehave.web.version>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>saucelabs</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>SAUCE_USERNAME</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <threads>5</threads>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>fail-fast</id>
      <properties>
        <ignore.failures>false</ignore.failures>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Whats the problem with pom.xml? I tried in eclipse-luna and intellij but i couldnot findout how to solve the problem? Is it a problem with jbehave code? Or with maven plugins?

Comment: From which Maven repository are you trying to fetch the 3.10-SNAPSHOT of jbehave-maven-plugin and is it actually there? For instance in [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave/jbehave-maven-plugin) the latest 3.x series build is 3.9.5 and then there's a 4.0-beta-1.

Comment: You are right tOmppa. What i have done is checked out new stable version from jbehave and trying to execute but getting an error with gmaven plugin.[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.3:generateStubs (default) on project etsy.com: startup failed:
[ERROR] /C:/jbehave-web-distribution-3.5.5-src/jbehave-web-3.5.5/archetypes/web-selenium-groovy-pico-archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/groovy/EtsyDotComSteps.groovy: 1: expecting '!', found 's' @ line 1, column 2.
[ERROR] #set( $symbol_pound = '#' ).

Comment: <properties>
    <jbehave.core.version>3.9.5</jbehave.core.version>
    <jbehave.web.version>3.5.5</jbehave.web.version>
    <jbehave.site.version>3.2</jbehave.site.version>
    <fluent.selenium.version>1.5.1</fluent.selenium.version>
    <selenium.version>2.21.0</selenium.version>
    <gmaven.version>1.3</gmaven.version>
    <groovy.version>1.8.6</groovy.version>
    <ignore.failures>true</ignore.failures>
    <threads>1</threads>
    <storyTimeoutInSecs>250</storyTimeoutInSecs>
    <skip>false</skip>
    <stories>**/EtsyDotComStories.java</stories>
  </properties>

Comment: You should update the question, comments aren't designed for long pastes of information, nor does everyone always read comments.